# Range error: maximum call stack size excedded in mongodb node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a nested schema in mongodb like below but it is giving me range error while inserting the values:

```
  var UserInfo = new Schema({

  userName : {type : String, required: true, index:{unique:true}},
  password : {type : String, required: true},
  country  : {type : String, required: true},
  city : {type : String , required: true},
  profileImage :{type: String, required:true},


});


var StatusUpdate= new Schema({

   status : {type: String},
   user : [UserInfo],
   likers : {type: Array, def :[]} 


});
```

I am sending a user name in post request and then if user found, i am inserting the user object to statusUpdate schema. But here it is giving me range error.

```
var user = mongoose.model('UserInfo');

user.findOne({userName: req.param('username')},function(e,o){

      if(e)
        callback('not found');
      else
      {

        statusUpdate.collection.insert({status: req.param('status'), user : o},     function(e,o)
        {
                   console.log(e);
                  if(e)
                    callback('unable to update status')
                  else
                    callback(o)
        });
      }

 });
```

Comment: which function? I want to insert the output of user into the statsupdate schema

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for reply , actually i was making a mistake. It is solved now.

Comment: Would be worth answering your own question if the learnings from your mistake might help others avoid doing the same :).